# Getting nose to ignore a function with 'test' in the name

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

The `nose` discovery process finds all modules whose name starts with `test`, and within them all functions which have `test` in the name and tries to run them as unit tests. See http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/man.html

I have a function whose name is say, `make_test_account`, in the file `accounts.py`. I want to test that function in a test module called `test_account`. So at the start of that file I do:

```
from foo.accounts import make_test_account
```

But now I find that nose treats the function `make_test_account` as a unit test and tries to run it (which fails because it doesn't pass in any parameters, which are required).

How can I make sure nose ignores that function specifically? I would prefer to do it in a way which means I can invoke nose as `nosetests`, without any command line arguments.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nose has a `nottest` decorator. However, if you don't want to apply the `@nottest` decorator in the module you are importing from you can also simply modify the method after the import. It may be cleaner to keep unit test logic close to the unit test itself.

```
from foo.accounts import make_test_account
# prevent nose test from running this imported method
make_test_account.__test__ = False
```

You can still use `nottest` but it has the same effect:

```
from nose.tools import nottest
from foo.accounts import make_test_account
# prevent nose test from running this imported method
make_test_account = nottest(make_test_account)
```

Comment: This looks to be a lot neater approach than dm295's accepted answer, since it does not impose test specific (and more importantly - **test framework specific**) code to be added in production code. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: This seems better because it will work across test runners without introducing a nose dependency.

Answer (score 13):

Tell nose that the function is not a test - use the [`nottest`](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing_tools.html#nose.tools.nottest) decorator.

```
# module foo.accounts

from nose.tools import nottest

@nottest
def make_test_account():
    ...
```