# nosetests mark imported method as non-test-case

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

nosetest uses heuristics to identify which functions are testcases. This can get awkward when importing a method with an ambiguous name for testing, e.g.:

foo/foo.py

```
def get_test_case(text):
    return "xyz"
```

(Note directory foo is excluded, this is not about nosetests identifying foo/foo.py as a testcase)

tests/test_foo.py

```
import unittest

# causes TypeError: get_test_case() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'
from foo.foo import get_test_case

class TestTestCasesReader(unittest.TestCase):

     def test_get_test_case(self):
         self.assertEquals(get_test_case("fooBar"), ...)
```

I know I can do this workaround in the test:

```
import unittest
import foo.foo

# ...
        self.assertEquals(foo.get_test_case("fooBar"), ...)
```

but it feels like there should be a better way to tell nosetest to lay off that `get_test_case` function.

Obviously I could also rename `get_test_case` to hide it from nosetests, that's not the answer I am looking for though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a relevant question: [Getting nose to ignore a function with 'test' in the name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33580779/getting-nose-to-ignore-a-function-with-test-in-the-name)

Two solutions were suggested in the question

1. using the [nottest](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/testing_tools.html#nose.tools.nottest) decorator in the module that defines `get_test_case`.

```py
from nose.tools import nottest

@nottest
def get_test_case(text):
    return "xyz"
```

2. using [nottest](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/testing_tools.html#nose.tools.nottest) in test code

```
import unittest
from nose.tools import nottest

from foo.foo import get_test_case
get_test_case = nottest(get_test_case)

class TestTestCasesReader(unittest.TestCase):

     def test_get_test_case(self):
         self.assertEquals(get_test_case("fooBar"), ...)
```